# Can I insert / query Excel cell values from the command line?

Tags: excel, batch-file

Let's say I've hidden some easter eggs in the garden, each of them with its own barcode. ...
Okay, let us not say it, let us *assume* it!

The eggs are managed by this Excel spreadsheet:

[image: Eggs in Eggsxcel]

Let us further assume that if the child finds an egg, he/she can hold it under the barcode scanner <s>everybody has in the garden for this purpose</s>.

**Is there any way to alter the excel spreadsheet from outside Excel (eg. with Batch)?**

A script that does that would wait for input from the barcode scanner and query `A:A` for the correct ID, check that the `C` cell is not already filled (you cannot find the same egg twice!) and input the current time into the latter cell.

Comment: I very much doubt you could do it directly, but it wouldn't be that hard to have a Visual Basic script do it. You could then run the VB script from the command line, with whatever parameters you need.

Comment: Export the spreadsheet to comma delimited text.  Batch files can easily process delimited files.

Comment: I am not the only one involved. If I were, there would be no Excel involved at all.